# Flatten a list of strings which contains sublists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a `list` of `strings` which contains a `sublist` os `strings`:

```
ids = [u'spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls', u'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk', [u'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F',
u'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']]
```

I tried to flatten it with:

```
[item for item in ids for item in sublist]
```

and

```
chain = itertools.chain(ids)
```

but these solutions split the strings...

how do I flatten the original `list` into

```
[u'spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls', u'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk', u'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F',u'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']
```

?

Comment: Can that sublist also have sublists, or do you know for certain it will be at most 2 deep?

Comment: Just test if `sublist` is actually a list and make it one if not: `[s for l in ids for s in (l if isinstance(l, list) else [l])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple loop with an `isinstance` check.

```
out = []
for i in ids:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        out.extend(i)
    else:
        out.append(i)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls',
 'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk',
 'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F',
 'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']
```

---

You could also use `itertools.chain`, but with an extra layer of preprocessing:

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable([i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in ids]))
print(out)
```

With the same output.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `isinstance(i, basestring)` should be used in Python 2.X

Comment: Maybe just check for a `list` instance, to avoid the `str` ambiguity...

Comment: indeed, I use python 2.X, and only with `instance(i, basestring)` it works

Comment: @outkast I took juan's excellent suggestion and converted it to check on list  for forward compatibility - python3 does not have the basestring type.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to cast any strings to lists:

```
import itertools
ids = [u'spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls', u'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk',   [u'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F',
u'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']]

new_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for i in b]))
```

Output:

```
[u'spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls', u'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk', u'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F', u'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to flatten the list.

```
def flatten(lst):
  if isinstance(lst, (str, unicode)):
    return [lst]
  return [unit for item in lst for unit in flatten(item)]

print(flatten(ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> [x for l in ids for x in (l if isinstance(l, list) else [l])]
[u'spotify:track:3ftnDaaL02tMeOZBunIwls', u'spotify:track:4CKjTXDDWIrS0cwSA9scgk', u'spotify:track:6oRbm1KOqskLTFc1rvGi5F', u'spotify:track:045sp2JToyTaaKyXkGejPy']
```

Which is similar to your list comprehension of `[item for item in ids for item in sublist]` but adding a test to see if it is actually a list we are looking at.